# what is the best event to use to update react store

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I am using redux to update states in my app, and I have a question about the best event to use to set the state of a component.

the situation is as below:
[image]

when I change the description and then click on the save button right after, I want the state will be updated and saved in the database.

so I tried to set the state in the event `onBlur` but if we still on focus on the description it's not saved before we click the save button.
so I thought to use `onMouseMove` but it identifies the mouse only when it's on the component place.
the last idea was to use `onKeyPress` but its look like its too much updates. and I think maybe there is better event or even some life-cycle to use in it.

the description component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    FormControl
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import _ from 'lodash';
let createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

/**
 * Helper class to limit re-render of components when editing title.
 * Rendered as a simple text while not focused / mouse over.
 */
const EditableLabel = createReactClass({
    propTypes: {
        value: PropTypes.any,
        onChange: PropTypes.func,
        editMode: PropTypes.oneOf(['always', 'click', 'double-click']),
        validateFunc: PropTypes.func
    },

    __inputRef: null,

    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            editMode: 'click'
        }
    },

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            value: this.props.value
        };
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.value !== this.props.value) {
            this.setState({value: newProps.value});
        }
    },

    _onChange(oldValue,newValue) {
        if(this.props.validateFunc && !this.props.validateFunc(newValue)) {
            // input is not valid
            this.setState({value: oldValue})
        } else {
            // input is valid or no validateFunc defined
            if (this.props.onChange) {
                if (oldValue !== newValue) {
                    this.props.onChange(newValue)
                }
            }
        }
    },

    render() {
        let props = _.omit(this.props, ['value', 'onChange', 'editMode','validateFunc','activeHref','activeKey']);

        let className = undefined;
        if (this.props.editMode === 'click') {
            className = "hover-border-visible";
        } else if (this.props.editMode === 'double-click') {
            // not implemented yet
        }
        return (
            <FormControl inputRef = {(ref) => {this.__inputRef = ref;}}
                         className={className}
                         {...props}
                         type="text" value={this.state.value}
                         onChange={(ev) => this.setState({value: ev.target.value})}
                         onBlur={(ev) => {
                             this._onChange(this.props.value,ev.target.value)
                         }}
                         onMouseMove={(ev) => {
                            this._onChange(this.props.value,ev.target.value)
                        }}
                         onFocus={(ev) => ev.target.setSelectionRange(0, ev.target.value.length)}
                        //  onKeyPress={(ev) => {
                        //          this._onChange(this.props.value, ev.target.value)
                        //  }}
            />
        );
    }
});

export default EditableLabel;
```

Comment: Are you working with an old codebase? Other than `render` none of the lifecycle methods are used much anymore. What is wrong with using the `onChange` event handler? What is the use case for all the others? I would say this seems like over-engineering but the other event handlers don't make sense really. Where is the relevant redux code? Why are you not dispatching actions to update the store?

Comment: The form state should go straight to redux (from the onchange events) and not be stored locally. That's the whole point of redux, saving everything locally and then trying to somehow sync at specific times defeats the purpose.

Comment: hey Drew Reese because onChange is exactly as onPress and I am afraid that too many changes will harm the fast of the app.

Comment: Are you observing any performance issues? Have you done any performance audits to track performance issues/bottlenecks? React is optimized pretty well out-of-the-box. Redux (reducer functions) generally also work quite well. Don't prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the store up to date it's normal. But you can use `useRef` hook and when user click on `Save` button update the store by take the value of input and remove the `onChange` attribute from `input`.

Something like this:

```
const inputEl = useRef(null);

const onSave = () => {
    const value = inputEl.current.value;
    this.setState({value})
    // rest of your save action
}

<input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
```